# Displaying UIImage Programatically in a Table Cell

Tags: ios, uiimage

I am working with some modified sample code and trying to make use of my customized storyboard cell (just an image view and 2 text labels) so that I can easily customize the cell in storyboard as needed.

My arrays are pretty simple:

```
teams = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Team1", @"Team2", nil];


embed = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"77.png", @"777.png", nil];
```

The code that follows all works great, with the exception of the UIImage code - which I can't seem to figure out.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"TeamCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    UIImageView *myimage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    myimage.image = [embed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    UILabel *teamLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    teamLabel.text = [teams objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



    return cell;
}
```

The code for the teamlabel works great and I am able to pass that along on a segue controller, but I have a serious issue with the UIImage Code.  Any ideas what I am goofing up?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting the image name will not work. Create an object of UIImage by below way.

```
myimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[embed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use some code like this:

```
myimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[embed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

That should do the trick.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `UIImage`s `imageNamed:` method.

```
myimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[embed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

You are currently assigning an `NSString` instead of a `UIImage` to your imageView.